# Corrosion of Aluminum by Baking soda

Tags: acid-base

An aqueous solution of sodium hydrogen carbonate corrodes aluminum foil quite readily. How do you explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sodium aluminate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_aluminate) is produced. The reaction is slower than the usual $NaOH + Al$ and liberates $CO_2$.

Comment: Is hydrogen produced also, like with NaOH? I guess not, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Nope, water instead.